# Cart Throb - Failed to connect error [SagePay]

Tags: cartthrob, error, ecommerce

I’m Struggling to get SagePay to play nicely. The error I’m getting is:

> Error
>
> Failed to connection 195.170.169.8: Permission Denied (7)

and it looks to me like it’s in and EE message box (See screenshot attached)

We’ve got everything in place such as HTTPS redirect, SSL, secure forms, IP addresses added to SagePay, in testing mode and using testing details but we keep hitting this error when we press “Pay” on the last step.

SagePay are saying it’s not on their end due to nothing even getting to their system (Transactions / Errors) and our host is saying it isn’t their fault and the firewall isn’t blocking anything!

*Sigh*

[image]

Comment: Have you set sage test server up? You need to authorise the IP that the payments are mount from. Usual process is to login to test.sagepay.co.uk and add your server IP. Run a test payment though, in test mode, then do the same dor live.sagepay.co.uk.

Comment: Oh and it does look like an odd message. Usually sage give you an error code you can look p.

Comment: @T2theC Yeah thats what we've done. It's set to test mode in Cart Throb, and the IP address of the server has been added to SagePay in both Test & Live. I just can't work out what is throwing the error... EE, SagePay or the Server?!

Comment: Email your vendor details to feedback@sagepay.com and I can take a look for you. If you have a txid for the transaction, that would be great too. Sage Pay Support

Comment: Thanks - We managed to fix this issue, and you'll be glad to hear it wasn't a SagePay problem but our hosts server @sage-pay

Answer (score 1):

Disabling "Selinux" on the server fixed this issue.